# Python: Changing multiple dates format in string to datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I am trying to convert different date in string format to datetime format. I have about ~ 1,000,000 rows of dates in column 'status_change_date'. The issue is that there are many different format and I do not know in what format they all are.

So, I am trying this function on my jupyter note:

```
def parsing_date(date_string):
    for date_format in ("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S%p", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S%p", "%-m/%-d/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%-d/%-m/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%-m/%-d/%Y %H:%M:%S%p", "%-d/%-m/%Y %H:%M:%S%p"):
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)
        except ValueError:
            raise
            print(date_string)
        raise ValueError('Something is wrong')
```

then,

```
data['status_chage_date'].apply(parsing_date)
```

I am printing out the error so I can take account one by one in my function till there is no error anymore. However, I am encountering this error message:

```
ValueError: time data '17/10/2019 05:49:51' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

or

```
strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

I thought I covered the format in my function and the second error is strange as I excluded rows that has None value.

What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

note that you raise when an error occurs! You need to test all your possibilities before:

```
import pandas as pd 

def parsing_date(date_string):
    d = None
    for date_format in ("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S%p", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S%p", "%-m/%-d/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%-d/%-m/%Y %H:%M:%S", "%-m/%-d/%Y %H:%M:%S%p", "%-d/%-m/%Y %H:%M:%S%p"):
        try:
            d = datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)
            break
        except:
            pass
    if d is not None:
        return d
    else:
        return pd.NaT
```

Also notice that if your day and month are both between the numbers 1 to 12,you will not be sure that your parsing to the correct datetime. If possible, you should seek what causes the different formats and parse them individually.

Comment: how can I test all the possibilities? with your code, I get a set of error as output.

Comment: in the loop, you try every possibility. When success, the code run the break line. Since d is not none, It will return d. If you test all possibilities without success, you return pd.NaT (None for Datetime)